# teaching over-calibration (from process control) to non-stats folks

Tags: terminology, stochastic-processes, overfitting, quality-control

When I took my courses in process control, they talked about "over-calibration", which is repeatedly tuning a process to attempt to reduce natural cause variation, as something that increased overall variation.  I'm trying to show a non-stats guy that it is a bad idea without getting too complicated.

Are there good examples that show how over-calibration increases output variation, and is a bad thing, for someone who doesn't know what the central limit theorem is?

I tried:

- googling it (main, images, videos; at least 3 pages deep; w/wo word check)
- looking in CV (keywords, partial keywords)
- wikipedia (statistical process control: links, keywords/vocab search)

My key word/phrases included:

- overcalibration
- calibration errors
- how not to handle process variation

I might be using the wrong term.  I know what I mean, but there may be a more technically meaningful word that when searched yields better results.

Comment: This is conceptually similar to [`overfitting`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/overfitting/info), isn't it?

Comment: It is similar.  In the world of factory-production, it is expensive.  Those managers who barely do algebra, they are born to mess up the process in this way.  Tinkering with a functioning system adds noise, and can make it less functioning or non-functioning.  If you only sample a subset of outgoing product, you can easily get customer-facing excursions that you didn't expect.  I call them "escapees".  Those can result in lawsuits, or price negotiation leverage that reduces your overall profit.  They are way more expensive than the cost of a widget.

Comment: I also suggest  there is a certain "sensitivity to initial conditions", in that small changes can outsized effects.